# Importing modules using Python in Abaqus script

Tags: python, import, tkinter

I am trying to import the `Tkinter` module into my `abaqus` script so that I can create popup boxes. I have tried appending the directory and tried both Tkinter and `tkinter` (although the file is `Tkinter.py`, I checked) Here is my code. The path that I appended to is the folder where the `Tkinter.py` file is located. The error that I get says `ImportError: No module named Tkinter`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.12-3\tools\SMApy\Lib\lib-tk')
from Tkinter import *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'\t'` in Python represent TAB character, not a backslashed and `t`.

If you want to represnt backslash and `t`, you should escape the backslash, or should use raw string literal.

```
'C:\\SIMULIA\\Abaqus\\6.12-3\\tools\\SMApy\\Lib\\lib-tk'
```

or

```
r'C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.12-3\tools\SMApy\Lib\lib-tk'
```